# Certificate Authority for myself/small organisation

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, client-certificates

I need a small CA software which meet following criteria:

1. CLI Interface (we all really hate gui things for server software, don't we?)
2. Issuing certificates for websites. So I just can install one root certificate on client machines to get rid of that warnings)
3. Issuing user certificates (as p12 and other stuff, so I can authenticate using them) with predefined values.

I was looking at tinyca but it's somewhat outdated and didnt worked for me well.

Openssl can do all of this, so I can code a bunch of shell scripts (or maybe Makefile) to automate this task. So I was wondering if already somebody did this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XCA](http://xca.sourceforge.net/) — A neat little tool, that fit perfectly to my requirements. No CLI though.